# Find merge candidates in TFS after a specific date or changeset ID using the command line

Tags: powershell, tfs

Reading the documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/tfvc/merge-command), it is not clear to me what the correct approach is to achieve my goal.

I want to do a baseless merge of changesets with specific keywords in their check-in comments from `Branch A` to `Branch B`. These two branches share the same parent, but do not share a parent-child relationship between themselves.

However, I am only interested in changesets committed after a certain date, **or** changesets with IDs larger than a specific threshold. I.e., it does not matter to me whether I look for merge candidates among changesets committed after DD/MM/YYYY, or among changesets with IDs larger than XXXXXX, insofar as I am not searching through the entire history.

How can I do this from the command line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how to do it:

```
$tf = get-item "c:\program files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\TF.EXE"
$lastMergedChangeNumber = 123456
$changesetsToMerge= 
    & $tf merge /baseless /candidate $/path/to/source . /recursive | ? { $_ -like '*SearchPatternHere*' } | % { $_.Split()[0]} | % { $_.Substring(0,6) } | % { [int]$_ } | Where-Object {$_ -gt $lastMergedChangeNumber }
if ($customBranchChangesetsToMerge -eq "There are no changes to merge." -Or !$customBranchChangesetsToMerge) {
    echo "*** No changesets found to merge. ***"
    return 
}
etc.
```